# :contains() function to vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning community! i need to transform this jquery code to vanilla JS,
In this case it uses: => :contains()

this is the code in jquery

```
var hoveredProjectActive = $(
    "#cursor-outer .project__caption:contains('" + hoveredProject + "')"
);
```

This is the code i made in vanilla JS, i made a function to get that .textContent inside some selector, with no success..

```
function contains(selector, text) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        return [].filter.call(elements, function(element){
          return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
        });
      }

      const hoveredProjectActive = contains("#cursor-outer .project__caption", `${hoveredProject}`);
```

Is anyone able to help me to transform this code, thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#contains_selector

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for your time, it does mean something like this: const hoveredProjectActive = [...document.querySelectorAll("#cursor-outer .project__caption")].filter((el) => el.textContent.includes(`${hoveredProject}`));

Comment: It's just `.included(hoveredProject)` - assuming you want a case-sensitive search), but yes.

Comment: `\`${hoveredProject}\`` is unnecessary. Just pass `hoveredProject` as it is already a string.

Comment: @ByGio1 You should not edit your own question with the answer . Just post the answer yourself! :)

Comment: P.S. I tested your original function. To me it seemed to work fine. What do you mean with "with no success.."?

Comment: @oligofren probably i was failing with pass variable, thanks for your comment, i'll give a try again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using .includes instead of a regex

```
function contains(selector, text) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    return [].filter.call(elements, function(element){
        return element.textContent.includes(text);
    });
}
```

But if you're deadset on using a regex then try this:

```
return (new RegExp(text)).test(element.textContent);
```

Note how the `RegExp` class constructor is wrapped in `()` and is prefixed with `new`

Comment: when use `*` `contains("*","apple")` your script will includes element that contains text and its all parent eg. element **p** have **apple** and script will include all **[html, body, div, p]**. You need to add **.childNodes[0]?** and change **textContent** to **nodeValue** to get element and exclude its parents like this `return element.childNodes[0]?.nodeValue?.includes(text);`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was passing variable incorrectly, just change on my initial function the way i pass a variable to function

From: (cause it is already an string)

```
`${hoveredProject}`
```

to:

```
hoveredProject
```